Error al instalar librería "spacy<2.2"
Estoy intentando instalar el paquete chatterbot, donde me sale un error al realizar el pip install.
Teniendo en cuenta ese error, he descargado diferentes paquetes por separado para intentar averiguar que paquete en concreto era el que fallaba. En este caso me ha fallado con el siguiente paquete:
py -m pip install "spacy<2.2"

Especificándose el siguiente error:

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


No sé si es porque no compila bien este paquete, ¿alguien se ha encontrado con este mismo problema?

Hola, seguramente es un fallo al compilar o construir el paquete causado por setuptools, distutils, el mismo compilador de C de turno... La traza del error que te muestra antes de la parte final que agregas a la pregunta sería de ayuda. No obstante, ¿En que versión de Python estas intentando instalar el paquete? ¿Qué sistema operativo? Ten en cuenta que spacy < 2.2 es como máximo spacy 2.1.9, que es algo vieja, en teoría la version más reciente de Python que soportaba ese paquete es Python 3.7...

Ese paquete soporta hasta Python 3.8 máximo según PyPi. Recomiendo mejor crear un entorno VENV con esa versión de Python y trabajes el proyecto desde ahí.

as seguido la documentacion de spacy? https://spacy.io/usage
